# How to select a value in jquery based on label

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

hi i have a select tag like this

```
<div id="container1">
<select id="firstbox">
<option value="1">kk</option>
<option value="2">kkk</option>
<option value="2">kkkk</option>
</select>
```

I tried selecting value kk using:

```
var modname="kk"
 $('#firstbox option:contains('+modname+')').prop('selected',true);
```

but this seems to bring up the last match "kkkk".
Is there any other function which gives exact match?
I don't wanna match using id's.

Comment: Use filter() and then in the callback do your match, if $(this).HTML() === 'kk' return

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this

For latest jQuery version

```
$('#firstbox option').filter(function () {
    return $(this).html() == modname;
}).prop('selected',true);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
$("#firstbox option:contains('" + firstbox + "')")
  .filter(function(i){
     return $(this).text() === firstbox;
})
.attr("selected", true)
```

OR

```
if($('#firstbox ').find('option[text="'+modname+'"]').length!=0)
  $('#firstbox ').find('option[text="'+modname+'"]').prop('selected',true);
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4HLqq/)**

Comment: Hey @Milind `$('#firstbox ').find('option[text="'+modname+'"]')` wont work

Comment: Also `('#firstbox option:contains('+ modname +')').prop('selected',true);` will select all options with kk as sub string

Comment: I dont think that is necessary for someone who is not OP.

Comment: I am asking for myself..can you do me little favor?..Please..please

Comment: I am waiting for your fiddle Milind

Comment: i am gonna need some time.will post the link soon

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46008/discussion-between-pilot-and-milind-anantwar)

Comment: @Pilot:added the fiddle.please see.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest would be,

```
$('#firstbox option').filter(function () {
    return $(this).text() == modname;
}).prop('selected', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should definitively use the value attribute to identify your option (or a "class" or a "data-*" attribute) instead of searching the text content to be more efficient and get cleaner code - and avoid bugs like the one you are facing. :)

I would suggest the following code :

```
var modval = "1" ;
$('#firstbox').val(modval);
```

Answer (score 0):

To select whole word delimited by whitespace, use tilda before "=":

```
$('#firstbox option[text~="'+modname+'"]').prop('selected',true);
```